# Deserializing XML From Rest service

Tags: c#, xml, rest, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am having trouble deserializing a Rest XML response into its object. If I serialize the data contract that I am expecting in the consumer application, the XML formatting is slightly different than what is actually being received from the Rest service. The data contract class that is sent from the service is the exact same as the one that I am expecting. If I change the XML received from the Rest service to the response expected by the consumer application, everything works.

The response that I am receiving from the Rest service is below.

```
<GeneralInquiryResponseCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.ServiceContract.Responses\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
  <ResultCode i:nil=\"true\"/>
  <ResultCodeDescription i:nil=\"true\"/>
  <ResultInfoDescription i:nil=\"true\"/>
  <ErrorMessage/>
  <IsSuccess>true</IsSuccess>
  <TransactionStatus>
    <Description>Transaction Successful</Description>
    <StatusCode>2000</StatusCode>
  </TransactionStatus>
  <AsOfDate>9999-12-31T00:00:00</AsOfDate>
  <FunctionalGroupingCode>302</FunctionalGroupingCode>
  <GeneralInquiryResponseContainer>
  </GeneralInquiryResponseContainer>
  <LastWMAValuationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastWMAValuationDate>
  <PolicyNumber>551372461</PolicyNumber>
  <TransactionExecutionDateTime>2014-01-14T15:05:05.859558</TransactionExecutionDateTime>
</GeneralInquiryResponseCollection>
```

The XML that I get when I serialize from the expected data contract is below.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<GeneralInquiryResponseCollection xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
  <ResultCode />
  <ResultCodeDescription>Success</ResultCodeDescription>
  <ResultInfoDescription>Result Info Description</ResultInfoDescription>
  <IsSuccess>true</IsSuccess>
  <TransactionStatus>
    <Description>Transaction Successful</Description>
    <StatusCode>2000</StatusCode>
    <HTTPStatusCode>OK</HTTPStatusCode>
  </TransactionStatus>
  <StatusCode>2000</StatusCode>
  <AsOfDate>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</AsOfDate>
  <FunctionalGroupingCode>302</FunctionalGroupingCode>
  <LastWMAValuationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastWMAValuationDate>
  <PolicyNumber>551372461</PolicyNumber>
  <TransactionExecutionDateTime>2014-01-14T14:40:59.0930535-07:00</TransactionExecutionDateTime>
</GeneralInquiryResponseCollection>
```

The main differences between them are as follows.

1. Consumer expects - 
   `<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>` - but Rest service does not send this.
2. Consumer expects - `<GeneralInquiryResponseCollection xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">`

Rest service sends `<GeneralInquiryResponseCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.ServiceContract.Responses\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">`

1. Consumer expects that properties of null value does not have the tag in the XML, but the Rest service sends the tag with i:nil=\"true\".

The code that deserializes is below where T is a GeneralInquiryResponseCollection.

```
using (var ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream())
{
    XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)Serializer.Deserialize(ResponseStream);
}
```

Below is the service contract

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.Interfaces;

namespace MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.ServiceContract.Responses
{
    [DataContract]
    public class GeneralInquiryResponseCollection : WMAResponse, IWMAResponse
    {

        #region Data Members

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime AsOfDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FunctionalGroupingCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<GeneralInquiryResponse> GeneralInquiryResponseContainer { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime LastWMAValuationDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? TransactionExecutionDateTime { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

GeneralInquiryResponse

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.Interfaces;

namespace MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.ServiceContract.Responses
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ClientResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ClientRoleResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(DCAFundResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(DCAResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(GMABResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(GMDBResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(GMIBResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(GWBResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InterestRateResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(MoneyFundSegmentResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(MRDFundResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PayoutFundResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PayoutResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PolicyFundResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PolicyResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PremiumBonusTransactionHistoryResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ProducerGroupSegmentResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(RebalancingResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(RebalancingScheduledFundResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(RebalancingUnscheduledFundResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(WithdrawalGrossTransactionHistoryResponse))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(WithdrawalSurrenderTransactionHistoryResponse))]
    public abstract class GeneralInquiryResponse : IGeneralInquiryResponse
    {
        #region Data Members

        [DataMember]
        public string ResponseIdentifier { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Ive been struggling with this one for a while and Im hitting dead ends. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means ResultCode is null

```
<ResultCode i:nil=\"true\"/>
```

This means ResultCode = ""

```
<ResultCode />
```

If you aren't just inquiring about nil, then please explain in more detail.  It's just a nillable property, defined as such in the schema.

To remove your namespace:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
```

Comment: Vijay, I am trying to find out why one program is serializing with <ResultCode i:nil=\"true\"/> and the other is not. How can I control the xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" that is serialized vs. xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.ServiceContract.Responses\"?

Comment: @RichardSchneider has put in a way to control the serializing in your model.  If it is not your model then I'm afraid there is little you can do.

Comment: @GWines - Could you post your service definition files?

Comment: I have updated the post to include the Service's service contract. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: @GWines - Change your DataContract attribute (I updated my post).

Comment: I did what you said to remove the namespace. I am still not deserializing though. I have updated my post with the GeneralInquiryResponse class

Comment: I read that the XMLSerializer can not deserialize a list of objects. Do you know if this is true? I changed GeneralInquiryResponseContainer to an array of GeneralInquiryResponse objects, but the GeneralInquiryResponseContainer is still the cause of the error with the deserialization.

Comment: I could not get this to actually work from a consumer deserialization perspective, but this answer was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ShouldSerializeXXX" method in your data model. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
public bool ShouldSerializeResultCode() 
{
   return ResultCode != null;
}
```

For data contracts you could use the `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` attribute instead of adding a method.  See [Data members default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string ResultCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Richard, that property attribute does help with the i=nil\"true\" problem, but it does not resolve the bigger problem of the xmlns attribute being http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance and http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEA.SmartApp.AdminGateway.ServiceContract.Responses on opposing sides of the service.

Comment: Why do you care about xmlns.  Its just a XML namespace ... it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: I just need to be able to deserialize the XML sent by the service in my consumer app. I am conjecturing as to why it wont. I was given an XSD from the service developer and I created the cs file with xsd.exe. Everything compiles, but I receive the error: {"There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."} when I use XmlSerializer to deserialize into the GeneralInquiryResponseCollection object.